# Select Date and Time in 2 steps using Ionic DateTime

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

Select Date and Time in 2 steps using Ionic DateTime: I want to use [Ionic DateTime](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/datetime/DateTime/) selecting date and time. The problem is that the picker with **pickerFormat="DD MMMM YYYY HH:mm"** gets complicated and too narrow, so I want to select date first and just after select the time. Any idea about how to do so?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can always separate them like this

```
<ion-item [hidden]="!!myDate">
      <ion-label>Date</ion-label>
      <ion-datetime (ngModelChange)="change(datePicker)" displayFormat="MM/DD/YYYY" [(ngModel)]="myDate"></ion-datetime>
    </ion-item>
    <ion-item [hidden]="!myDate" >
      <ion-label>Time</ion-label>
      <ion-datetime #datePicker
      (ionCancel)="myDate=undefined" displayFormat="HH:mm" [(ngModel)]="myTime"></ion-datetime>
    </ion-item>

    <h1 [hidden]="!myTime">result is {{myDate}} : {{myTime}} </h1>
```

then in ts

```
change(datePicker){    
  datePicker.open();
}
```

Then concatenate the results

```
this.dateTime= this.myDate + ":" + this.myTime;
```

Here's a [DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-xwxabs?file=pages%2Fhome%2Fhome.ts)

Comment: Well, two field forcing the user to click two controls is not good for UX. I guess I can use *ngIf to show the date first, and after setting the date, hide the control and show the time control. Then after setting the time, show the date+time in a final control. However, when jumping from the date selection to the time selection, how can I open the time picker directly, without forcing to click again the DateTime input to show the picker???

Comment: Awesome!! Demo works great!! I'll copy now. Thank you